# Passing Environment Variables to App While Running Via XCode Bot Integration

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, environment-variables, bots

I am trying to pass username/password values to my application while running an integration on an XCode bot. I am entering the variable:value information in the "Environment" section of the edit bot window, and I am referencing the environment variables like so in my source code.

```
let env = NSProcessInfo.processInfo().environment
if let username = env["username"]
{
    if let password = env["password"]
    {
        signIn(username, passVal: password)
    }
}
```

This approach is working when I am putting my environment variables in my scheme, however that is not an option considering my CI setup. Does anyone know of any quirks involving the "Environment" section of the Xcode Bot editor which would be causing this issue?

Comment: If you put the environment variables in the scheme itself, and the Xcode bot is running based on that (shared) scheme, won't that code work for you and for the bot?

Comment: @keithbhunter It would, but I have 5 bots running concurrently, using the same scheme, which I need to keep on separate accounts. I could break this out into different schemes which are only different by their environment variables but I'm looking for an alternative to that approach.